# How to collect messages past a specific date in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

Im trying to add a function that will check the number of messages sent by a user within the last 2 days, right now im looping through all the channels history and checking the message 1 at a time, but with a guild that gets thousands of messages a day this takes a long time, is there a way that i can specify a max amount of time to look back?

heres my current code

```py
# This is also inside of a cog
now = datetime.datetime.now()
joined_on = ctx.author.joined_at
delta = datetime.timedelta(joined_on, now)
if delta.days >= 2:
    message = 0
    for channel in ctx.guild.channels:

        if channel.id != 863871156298055751:

            for message in channel.messages:
                sent_at = message.created_at
                delta = datetime.timedelta(sent_at, now)

                if delta.days <= 2 and message.author.id == ctx.author.id:
                    messages += 1
```

Comment: @Paul That gets their DM history

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a version of the `history` that works on the channels. You can also specify a time frame to look at.

See [`TextChannel.history`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=history#discord.TextChannel.history).

```py
    counter = 0
    for channel in ctx.guild.channels:
        try:
            if not isinstance(channel, discord.TextChannel):
                continue
            # set a hard limit on the messages taken, or limit the amount of time to search
            async for msg in channel.history(limit=100, after=datetime.datetime.utcnow()-datetime.timedelta(hours=1)):
                # change this
                if msg.author.id == ctx.author.id:
                    counter += 1
        except discord.errors.Forbidden:
            pass
    await ctx.send(counter)
```

Comment: i did manage to figure this out using your posted method, because the person who pointed me to the correct documentation deleted their comment i'll mark your answer as correct